# How to implement persistent counter over Oracle sequence with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to have a persistent, distributed counter. My idea is to use a database sequence. Only sequence. I do not want to have a table, because I will not populate the table. I just need a sequence of unique numbers.

I don't want to use naive `select mys-seq.nextval from dual` (or `org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer`) because I would like to use sequence caching ability - I do not want to hit the database every time I need a new number.

I guess I should use `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator`, but I cannot find any example of how to use it "standalone", without entity.

Unfortunately, all examples I found describes how to configure entity id generation with the sequence.

PS. I have the Spring Boot app.

Comment: `I do not want to hit database every time I need new number` then you are very probably wrong about using anything database based

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution for my problem: I can treat each number from database sequence as a range of numbers to use. For example, if sequence returns 5, it means that reserved range for my counter is 5000 - 5999.

In that solution I will hit database once for thousand numbers.

*Initially I thought I have to utilize internal database level sequence number caching, but the same result I can achieve with trivial application level caching*